# New Bootstrap 4 offset solution?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4 Alpha, [we had offsets](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns). Now that Bootstrap 4 has been released officially, [we have a bad alternative](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns).

Previously, you could achieve something like:

```
<div class="col-2"></div>
<div class="col-2">This is offset by 2</div>
<div class="col-2"></div>
<div class="col-2">This is offset by 2</div>
<div class="col-2"></div>
<div class="col-2">This is offset by 2</div>
```

Simply by doing:

```
<div class="col-2 offset-2">This is offset by 2</div>
<div class="col-2 offset-2">This is offset by 2</div>
<div class="col-2 offset-2">This is offset by 2</div>
```

All by adding the `offset-2` class to the element. You can't do this anymore, and if you're looking for a way to do the first thing I said, you need to do it in that order.

Is it really true, that the newest Bootstrap 4 release disgarded this? Is there an alternative to this, which doesn't require hacking up the source file?

Answer (score 0):

The new grid system in Bootstrap 4 still supports [offsetting columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) with  the `offset-*` classes.

See the snippet below:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 offset-2">Offset by 2</div>
    <div class="col-2 offset-2">Offset by 2</div>
    <div class="col-2 offset-2">Offset by 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funny, it was just added a few days ago. This is how the "old" (few days ago) page looked like: https://i.imgur.com/bbL27jX.png - Now it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/apmU8jf.png